# What are the sources of electric and magnetic fields that produce lights?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, charge, dipole, antennas

Electromagnetic waves are formed as a consequence of the interference of electric and magnetic fields. I wonder where are these fields coming from that form the light? Does the fields have to be constant in order to produce waves? Otherwise how are lights going to be affected by the non-constant fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Classical electromagnetism, Electromagnetic waves can be caused by:

**Accelerating charges:**

As seen from jefimenkos equations, accelerating charge causes what we call "light".

**The initial conditions of the universe allowing for a non zero homogenous solution:**

Background EM wave solutions can exist without charges present, as seen in the homogenous wave equation. If the universes initial condition is such that this solution is non zero, then there would be EM waves as a consequence of our universe existing the way it does in general.